# how to run commands separately with tox-travis

Tags: travis-ci, tox

I am trying to run lint and tests separately with tox-travis, but I cannot seem to get the right combo.

Here are the two base files:

tox.ini

```
[tox]
envlist = py27, py34, py35, py36, lint

[travis]
python =
    3.6: py36
    3.5: py35
    3.4: py34
    2.7: py27   

[travis:env]
LINT = 
     yes: py36, lint

[testenv:lint]
....

[testenv]
...
commands = 
    pip install -U pip
    py.test --basetemp={envtmpdir}
```

travis.yml

```
language: python
python:
  - 3.6, lint
  - 3.5
  - 3.4
  - 2.7
matrix:
  include:
    - python: 3.6
      env:
        - LINT=yes
install: pip install -U tox-travis
script: tox
```

- When `python={3.6,3.5,3.4,2.7}` and `LINT` is not set only tests are
  run. (correct).
- When `python=3.6` and `LINT=yes` it runs NEITHER lint
  or tests. (incorrect)

---

Setting

```
LINT = 
     yes: lint
```

- When `python={3.6,3.5,3.4,2.7}` and `LINT` is not set only tests are
  run. (correct).
- When `python=3.6` and `LINT=yes` it runs neither
  tests or lint. (incorrect)

---

Setting: `3.6: py36,lint` and `yes: lint` runs lint whenever python=3.6 regardless of LINT value.

---

What am I doing wrong here?